# Send data after ACTION_SHUTDOWN is received

Tags: android

I know that the apps receive a ACTION_SHUTDOWN broadcast event when the device is shutting down. 
When an application receives the shutdown, is there still an opportunity to send data packets out, or does android block such attempts(or does the platform tear down the network stack before it can go out).

Comment: Why not just try it? :) Though I doubt it's possible as the system goes down very quickly; you couldn't be guaranteed that you have a data connection anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you can still send out some data packets after receiving the ACTION_SHUTDOWN event before the phone dies completely.